# Isomorphism between Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

This is an exercise (cf. exe 2.11 in the Erdmann and Wildon's book)

Define $$  gl_S(n, F) = \{ x\in gl(n,F)|\ x^t S = -Sx \} $$
  Here $t$ is transpose.

Then let $T=P^tSP$ and show that $$ gl_T(n,F)=gl_S(n,F) $$ wher $P$ is invertible.

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be using both a $^t$ and a $^T$. Are those suppose to be the same (ie, both meaning transpose)?

Comment: I corrected. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathfrak{gl}_{T}(n,\mathbb{F})$, then $x^tT=-Tx$. As $T=P^tSP$, so we get\[x^tP^tSP=-P^tSPx\iff (PxP^{-1})^tS=-SPxP^{-1}.\]Consequently, we can define $\phi:\mathfrak{gl}_{T}(n,\mathbb{F})\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_{S}(n,\mathbb{F})$ by $\phi(x)=PxP^{-1}$. The remained details are plain.